# Kohana : how to get the sub-request's (HMVC) cookie changes

Tags: cookies, kohana, hmvc

I use the following code to perform sub-request in HMVC structure:

A request to "page1" will make a sub-request to "page2" by the following code:

```
$request = Request::factory('/page2')
           ->method(Request::POST)
           ->post($postData)
           ->execute();
```

The execution in "page2" will add / change the value of a cookies item by

```
setcookie('new_var', $newValue);
```

Now I need to capture the new value of the cookie "new_var" in "Page1". So how can I do that?

PS: Due to some limitations, I have to set the 'new_var' in cookie, so putting it to session is not an answer.

==========update =============

As suggested by zerkms, I did something like this:

```
$response = Request::factory('/page2')
           ->method(Request::POST)
           ->post($postData);

//before
error_log(print_r($response->cookie(), TRUE));

$response->execute();

//after
error_log(print_r($response->cookie(), TRUE));
```

the result of the "before" and "after" log entries are both empty array. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kohana you'd better used [Response::cookie()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Response#cookie) method.

In this case you can use this method for both retrieving and setting cookies (even in the same request)

Comment: Response::cookie is not static method and sets/gets cookies for the current response. It can be called only in $this->response scope. Response stores cookies in $this->_cookies protected var and not setting its immediately on function call. I think that in this case [Cookie helper](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Cookie) will be better solution.

Comment: @atma: of course it is not a static method ;-) But that is common **convention** to write complete signature of the method (either static or instance one). Also - read his question once again, `Cookie::set()` doesn't help him, as long as he wants to set and read in the **same** request

Comment: Thanks, I know about conventions. Lets go to read the post again: The execution in **"page2"** will add / change the value of a cookies item by... Now I need to capture the new value of the cookie "new_var" in **"Page1"**. So Request::initial() and some subrequest are the same?

Comment: @atma: come on, we can set cookies for same request object. Yes, we **can** get the same (outer) request object in inner request

Comment: @atma, zerkms : thx for your help. i'm not with my code right now so I can't test with your suggestion, but since you have mentioned Response->cookie() and the cookie class, and I also find there is Request::current()->cookie(). They are really confusing me. I therefore created another question about their differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543811/difference-between-the-kohanas-request-cookie-response-cookie-and-the-cooki

Comment: @zerkms: I tried Response->cookie() but it doesn't work. Pls see my question update for my codes. Thx!

Comment: @LazNiko: `cookie` method accepts 2 arguments: `name, value` in case when you want to set cookie, and just `name` when you need to read its value http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Response#cookie

Comment: @zerkms: yes, you're right, but the two arguments are optional. if no argument is given, it should return the whole array of the cookies.

Comment: @LazNiko: yep. And how did you set the cookies?

Comment: @zerkms: setcookie('new_var', $newValue);

Comment: @LazNiko: as I said - you need to use `Response::cookie()` for both retrieving and setting cookies