# Difference between the Kohana's Request cookie(), Response cookie() and the Cookie class?

Tags: cookies, kohana

I'm working on a program dealing with cookies under the kohana's HMVC structure, and I find that Kohana has 3 ways to get/set the cookie. They are

`Request::current()->cookie()`, `Response->cookie()`, and the cookie class (`Cookie::set(), get()`)

And PHP has a native `setcookie()` function and `$_COOKIE` to deal with cookies too.

Could anyone explain their differences and, what are the situations that they should be used respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`Request::cookie()` prior to calling `Request::execute()` on the same object is used to set the cookies that will be send (or have been sent in case of the initial request) along with the rest of the request.
`Request::cookie()` during a `Request::execute()` will replace `$_COOKIE`.

`Response::cookie()` during a `Request::execute()` will replace `setcookie()`.
`Response::cookie()` after a `Request::execute()` is used to get the cookies set back by the server.

The Cookie helper will sign your cookies and is used by HTTP_Header to set cookies set to the Response object in your initial Request object (see `Response::send_headers()` in `index.php`).
You probably do not want to use it yourself directly if you are trying to code HMVC safe.

Comment: Are there any pirority for each of them? Let's say a request will execute several methods and sub-requests in a sequence, and some of the methods / sub-requests will update a "CommonKey" cookie, with different approaches as mentioned in the question, so which approach will finally be effective?